# Is there any way I can implement a chat on an android app that already uses a JAVA webservice with REST API?

Tags: java, android, rest, google-cloud-messaging, chat

I'm developing an Android app that consumes a java webservice with REST API and make the DB(MySQL) persistence with Hibernate. Now, I want to add a chat on the application, but I don't really know how to start, if I use GCM or other options, so far it's working with threads that check for new messages every second. However, this seems very wrong as it consumes too much of the server. Is there a better solution, maybe a tutorial or just some tips on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this will be a two-way communication because it will be a chat app (server -> client, client -> server). In the case of using GCM, you will need to communicate via an XMPP library.

On the server side, an XMPP library should be able to register a packet listener that listens for incoming messages. Look at [this](https://github.com/writtmeyer/gcm_server/blob/master/src/com/grokkingandroid/sampleapp/samples/gcm/ccs/server/CcsClient.java#L398) implementation.

On the client side, you need to register a listener as well. The [sample code](https://github.com/google/gcm/tree/master/samples/android) should suffice to explain this.